# Web library/framework for real-time flow diagrams

Tags: open-source, library, web

I am looking for a web library/framework that would allow me to place nodes on a diagram, link them with "tubes" and somehow visualize flow between the nodes. I am only looking for the visualization part. Does such thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram with nodes and connectors. The library is not open source, but a community license is available (details below)

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/mcleq2ss)

[image: Diagram JS with animated connectors]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.